# Combine 'short' and 'medium' duration in YouTube API search

Tags: youtube-api

I used the following URL to search "music" via YouTube API with 'short' duration (< 4 mins)

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=music&type=video&order=date&maxResults=25&videoDuration=short&key={your key}

If I wanna search it with 'short' and 'medium' duration together, how can I edit the URL?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is not yet possible, you can try and follow the reported [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5263). For now you just have to make separate request for "short" and "meduim" then combine the list. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can not do it with just one API call.